# Tensorflow throwing distributed_function error

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science, tensorflow2.0

I am new to ML and tensorflow and trying to train and use a standard text generation model. When I go to train the model I get **this error**:

```
Train for 155 steps
Epoch 1/5
  2/155 [..............................] - ETA: 4:49 - loss: 2.5786
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-d70c02ff4270> in <module>()
----> 1 model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[58,87] = 63 is not in [0, 63)
     [[node sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-131-d70c02ff4270>:1) ]]
     [[VariableShape/_24]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[58,87] = 63 is not in [0, 63)
     [[node sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-131-d70c02ff4270>:1) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_distributed_function_95797]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup/92192 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Input Source operations connected to node sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup:
 sequential_12/embedding_12/embedding_lookup/92192 (defined at /usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py:81)

Function call stack:
distributed_function -> distributed_function
```

**Data**

```
data['title'] = [['Sentence'],['Sentence2'], ...]
```

**Data Prep**

```
tokenizer = keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=209, lower=False, char_level=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df['title'])
df['encoded_with_keras'] = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df['title'])

dataset = df['encoded_with_keras']
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(dataset, padding='post')

dataset = dataset.flatten()

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)

sequences = dataset.batch(seq_len+1, drop_remainder=True)


def create_seq_targets(seq):
    input_txt = seq[:-1]
    target_txt = seq[1:]
    return input_txt, target_txt

dataset = sequences.map(create_seq_targets)

batch_size = 128

buffer_size = 10000

dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size).batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
```

**Model:**

```
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index)
embed_dim = 128
rnn_neurons = 256

epochs = 5

# Directory where the checkpoints will be saved
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
# Name of the checkpoint files
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")

checkpoint_callback=tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True)

def create_model(vocab_size, embed_dim, rnn_neurons, batch_size):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None], mask_zero=True))
    model.add(LSTM(rnn_neurons, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(rnn_neurons, return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
    return model

model.fit(dataset, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

I have tried changing almost all model settings, and playing around with custom tokenization and data prep. But this starts training and on the 2nd step of 155 I get this error. I'm not sure where to start any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the batch_size to something like 32, 16 or 8 . Apparently, for rtx 2060/70/80 there’s a tensorflow bug that makes it run out of memory.

Comment: I have the same problem and changing batch_size is not the solotion

Answer (score 2):

In a similar situation the below snippet helped.

```
import tensorflow as tf
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], enable=True)
```

Comment: What is exactly physical_devices[0]? It's this just valid for Google Colab?

Comment: We don't know whether the poster is using a GPU.

Comment: This answer is not a good one, it lacks explanation of the snipper and assumes the original poster is on a GPU (and also hardcodes the GPU ID).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by adding **validation_data** into the **fit()** function

> model.fit(X,validation_data = y)

Answer (score 0):

I think most answers here miss the crux of the problem here. The Tensorflow model here tries to perform an Embedding Lookup operation for an index that does not exist in the Embedding Layer defined. Most answers point to VRAM issues, but it is very possible that this message will come due to simple lookup issues.

To fix this, you could define your own dictionary and encode the labels, and for every unknown label, you can return `0` or `-1` and keep an unknown category.

Some sample code to solve this sort of a problem (Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527381/unseen-category-in-validation-set-gives-error-when-using-keras) post, seems to work for test data):

**Class for Custom Dictionary Processing:**

```
class EmbeddingMapping:
    """
    An instance of this class should be defined
    for each categorical variable you want to use.
    """
    def __init__(self, series: pd.Series) -> None:
        # get a list of unique values
        values = series.unique().tolist()

        # dictionary mapping
        self.embedding_dict: Dict[str, int] = {value: int_value + 1 for int_value, value in enumerate(values)}
        self.num_values: int = len(values) + 1  # +1 for unknown categories

    def get_mapping(self, value: str) -> int:
        # return value if it was seen in training
        if value in self.embedding_dict:
            return self.embedding_dict[value]
        else:
            return 0
```

**Building the Mappings:**

```
# build mappings
res_dict_train: Dict[str, EmbeddingMapping] = {}
for var in categorical_features:
    embd_train = EmbeddingMapping(X_train_categorical[var])
    temp_series_train = X_train_categorical[var].apply(embd_train.get_mapping)

    res_dict_train[var] = temp_series_train

X_train_categorical = X_train_categorical.assign(**res_dict_train)
```

Model combining categorical and numerical features:

```
# Keras
# Categorical vars
models_lst = []
inputs = []
for cat_feature in categorical_features:
    print('---------------------------------------')
    print(f'Info for categorical feature {cat_feature}')
    input_i = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    inputs.append(input_i)
    num_categories = EmbeddingMapping(X_train_categorical[cat_feature]).num_values
    print(f"Number of categories: {num_categories}")
    embedding_size = min(np.ceil(num_categories/2), 50)     # rule of thumb
    embedding_size = int(embedding_size)
    print(f'Embedding size: {embedding_size}')
    model_i = Embedding(input_dim=num_categories, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=1, name=f'embedding_{cat_feature}')(input_i)
    model_i2 = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(model_i)

    models_lst.append(model_i2)

# layer for numerical
input_numerical = Input(shape=(len(numerical_features),), dtype='float32')
numerical_model = Reshape(target_shape=(2,))(input_numerical)
models_lst.append(numerical_model)
inputs.append(input_numerical)

concatenated = concatenate(models_lst, axis=-1)
mymodel = Dense(50, activation="relu")(concatenated)
mymodel2 = Dense(15, activation="relu")(mymodel)
mymodel3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(mymodel2)

final_model = models.Model(inputs, mymodel3)

final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc', 'binary_accuracy'])

final_model.fit(x=train_input_list, validation_split=0.2, y=y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=128)
```

To explain the code, it creates an embedding layer, and if the embedding lookup fails in any case, we assign an unknown variable. If you have a custom Data object such as a Pandas DataFrame, you could make your Numerical and Categorical features discrete, and apply a model in this fashion, or just use the Categorical model code with the mapping shown above. An alternative is to use a Scikit-Learn `OrdinalEncoder` (added since SKLearn 0.24.2), but I find this simpler as it's easy to maintain.