# Unseen category in validation set gives error when using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have data that consists of numerical and categorical variables. The categorical variables have a lot of categories so I'm using Embeddings to represent these. My model is a simple neural network.
I know that when you define the Embedding layer you need to pass `input_dim=number of categories + 1` in order to account for unseen-in-training categories. This is what I had done.
Also, when encoding these categories to numerical values in order to input them into the neural network I have done the following:
1. Enumerate all the unique values in the **training set** and put them into a dictionary. Save also a variable called `num_values` which is the number of unique categories + 1.
2. For the validation set, if the value is not in the dictionary then I give it the value of `num_values`.

This introduces a problem because when I want to evaluate the model (using `model.predict()`) I get an error like:

```py
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,0] = 118752 is not in [0, 118752)
```

This is because I had an unseen-before category in the validation set in some variable, and it was mapped to `num_values`, but `num_values` **is never assigned to any category in the training set** because the dictionary building takes place on the training set. I don't how to solve this issue.

I am using Keras 2.3.1 and Tensorflow 1.13.1

The relevant code:

```py
class EmbeddingMapping:
    """
    An instance of this class should be defined
    for each categorical variable you want to use.
    """
    def __init__(self, series: pd.Series) -> None:
        # get a list of unique values
        values = series.unique().tolist()

        # dictionary mapping
        self.embedding_dict: Dict[str, int] = {value: int_value + 1 for int_value, value in enumerate(values)}
        self.num_values: int = len(values) + 1  # +1 for unknown categories

    def get_mapping(self, value: str) -> int:
        # return value if it was seen in training
        if value in self.embedding_dict:
            return self.embedding_dict[value]
        # else return num_values which is the same for all
        # unseen values
        else:
            return self.num_values


# build mappings
res_dict_train: Dict[str, EmbeddingMapping] = {}
res_dict_val: Dict[str, EmbeddingMapping] = {}
for var in categorical_features:
    embd_train = EmbeddingMapping(X_train_categorical[var])


    temp_series_train = X_train_categorical[var].apply(embd_train.get_mapping)
    temp_series_val = X_val_categorical[var].apply(embd_train.get_mapping)

    res_dict_train[var] = temp_series_train
    res_dict_val[var] = temp_series_val

X_train_categorical = X_train_categorical.assign(**res_dict_train)
X_val_categorical = X_val_categorical.assign(**res_dict_val)

# Keras
# Categorical vars
models_lst = []
inputs = []
for cat_feature in categorical_features:
    print('---------------------------------------')
    print(f'Info for categorical feature {cat_feature}')
    input_i = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')
    inputs.append(input_i)
    num_categories = EmbeddingMapping(X_train_categorical[cat_feature]).num_values
    print(f"Number of categories: {num_categories}")
    embedding_size = min(np.ceil(num_categories/2), 50)     # rule of thumb
    embedding_size = int(embedding_size)
    print(f'Embedding size: {embedding_size}')
    model_i = Embedding(input_dim=num_categories, output_dim=embedding_size, input_length=1, name=f'embedding_{cat_feature}')(input_i)
    model_i2 = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(model_i)

    models_lst.append(model_i2)

# layer for numerical
input_numerical = Input(shape=(len(numerical_features),), dtype='float32')
numerical_model = Reshape(target_shape=(2,))(input_numerical)
models_lst.append(numerical_model)
inputs.append(input_numerical)

concatenated = concatenate(models_lst, axis=-1)
mymodel = Dense(50, activation="relu")(concatenated)
mymodel2 = Dense(15, activation="relu")(mymodel)
mymodel3 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(mymodel2)

final_model = models.Model(inputs, mymodel3)

final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc', 'binary_accuracy'])

final_model.fit(x=train_input_list, validation_data=(val_input_list, y_val), y=y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=128)
```

I get the error when the epoch ends and the model tries to compute validation statistics.

Comment: Where is the code causing the problem?

Comment: @Anwarvic added now..

Answer (score 2):

with this line:

```
self.embedding_dict: Dict[str, int] = {value: int_value + 1 for int_value, value in enumerate(values)}
```

you are adding +1 to all your integer encoding so you are transforming your values from [0,max_cat] to [1,max_cat+1] and that it's correct

but doing this, the best way to encode unseen categories is with 0, so you have to modify:

```
    def get_mapping(self, value: str) -> int:
        # return value if it was seen in training
        if value in self.embedding_dict:
            return self.embedding_dict[value]
        # else return 0 which is the same for all unseen values
        else:
            return 0
```

hope this can help you

Comment: Solid answer to a solid question!